# How to call function is sql select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have sql select and I need use some function for status_bid field? like this:

```
        SELECT 
             `N`.`_id` as `_id`,
             `N`.`created_at` as `created_at`,
             CASE
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 1 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(1).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 2 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(2).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 3 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(3).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 4 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(4).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 5 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(5).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 6 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(6).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 10 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(10).'"
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 11 THEN "'.$this->getBidStatusString(11).'"                    
                ELSE "0"
             END as `status_bid`,                 
             ..........
             ..........
```

But `CASE WHEN ELSE END` no pretty for me. How to change like this

```
    if (`N`.`status_bid` IS NOT NULL) {
        '".$this->getBidStatusString(`N`.`status_bid`).'" as `status_bid`  
    }
```

I have php function

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBidStatusString($id)
{
    if (array_key_exists($id, Bit::getBidStatusSerialized())) {
        return Bit::getBidStatusSerialized()[$id];
    }
}
```

this is possible in sql?

Comment: What is `$this->getBidStatusString()`? Is it a PHP method? Show the code

Comment: What does function **$this->getBidStatusString** do?

Comment: php function `public function getBidStatusString($id)`  check array key and return array element value -> return string
UPDATE QUESTION

Comment: if you want to call php function in sql query then it wont possible you need to write sql function or trigger to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do this in your SQL. Iterate over your data after you get data from mysql. Or maybe you can call **getBidStatusString** when you will need it. For example

```
<span><?=Bit::getBidStatusSerialized()[$data['id']]?>
```

Comment: I know, but I interesting how do this is sql select

Comment: Then all you need to do is study how to create a MySQL procedure http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: You can't do it in a SQL Select without jumping through hoops while whistling Dixie.... The SQL Select is executed by SQL, which has absolutely no idea that PHP even exists. In theory, if you have complete control over your database server, you can create an SQL function that is capable of calling an external PHP script, but that's extremely inefficient and problematic

Comment: As @MarkBaker said, MySQL dont know about PHP, so you cant use PHP functions within SQL query. But you can translate your PHP function into MySQL procedure and then use it. But I still think that what you need is to be done in PHP script...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in PHP and building a query in a string that you will use later in a query then this is perfectly possible.

See this sample code below.

```
<?php
class aa
{
    public $arr = array('aa','bb','cc');

    public function getBidStatusString($id){
        return $this->arr[$id];
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $q = "SELECT
             `N`.`_id` as `_id`,
             `N`.`created_at` as `created_at`,
             CASE
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 1 THEN '{$this->getBidStatusString(1)}'
                WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 1 THEN '{$this->getBidStatusString(2)}'
                ELSE `0`
             END as `status_bid`";

        return $q;

    }
}

$aa = new aa();
echo $aa->query();
```

Will return:

```
SELECT
     `N`.`_id` as `_id`,
     `N`.`created_at` as `created_at`,
     CASE
        WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 1 THEN 'bb'
        WHEN `N`.`status_bid` = 1 THEN 'cc'
        ELSE `0`
     END as `status_bid`
```